# Facebook isn't showing the names of exact number of people who liked a specific post

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-like

I am talking about a post in a closed Facebook group. The post had about 1900 likes. When click on “1900 others” it showed a list of names. So for some reason the number of names were counted after transferring it to an Excel file. And it just gave 497 names. What does this mean? Does it mean that Facebook will only generate random names from the perspective of the user who clicked in it (for example in my case 497)? Or is it an error with Facebook? (Actually there were only 497 likes.)

Comment: What does it mean "names of exact number"? Are you sure the number of people has any names? I guess there is something wrong in your title.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that Facebook will only generate random names from the perspective of the user who clicked in it

Coupled with a user's (those who liked the post) privacy settings, yes.